# Data-toggle disable the a tags inside

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have an div with `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` it works fine.
How ever when i have links in the div they wil activate the modal too. is there a way to disable the a tags from opening the modal?

```css
.team-section-inner{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="team-section-inner" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <h1>activates modal</h1>
  <a href="#footer">Activates modal but needs to be disabled</a>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show us your code :)

Comment: @Gobbin inserted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is bubbling. You need to cancel the event when you click on the a in the div itself. You need jQuery for this though. You can stop that by using `stopPropagation()`. Docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_bubbling) is a good explanation of what Event Bubbling is.

```js
$('.team-section-inner a').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.team-section-inner{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="team-section-inner" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <h1>activates modal</h1>
  <a href="#footer">Activates modal but needs to be disabled</a>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't; simply fix it by adding a `div` before the `h1` that triggers the modal

```
<div class="team-section-inner">
  <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <h1>activates modal</h1>
  </div>
  <a href="#footer">Activates modal but needs to be disabled</a>
</div>
```

Comment: "You can't" is NEVER an answer in the world of programming!

Comment: @Gobbin I totally agree; and your answer works like a charm; however, if he wants to create a simple text that opens the modal then it doesn't make any sense to stop the propagation of the event; what if there's other buttons / actions... my answer was based on that; that's it. it's more like `you shouldn't` than `you can't`